# Programa complicado

Tags: c#, c, visualg

Estou já a um tempo tentando fazer um programa que faça o seguinte: Peça a um usuário para digitar uma quantidade de números e depois para digitar a quantidade de números que ele deseja ter na combinação e depois o programa imprima as combinações  e as quantidades de combinações

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao Stackoverflow em Português. Não entendi seu problema, vc poderia adicionar mais informações e ser mais especifico? Tem algum código? Como seria essas combinações? Faça um [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender como o site funciona.

Comment: C#, C e Visual G são linguagens diferentes uma das outras, só para início do assunto.

Answer (score 1):

Esses números podem se repetir? 
se sim, o número de combinações e N! (onde N é a quantidade de números que ele quer), caso não se repitam fica N * (N-1) * (N-2) * ... * 1!

Pelo que entendi você que saber quantas vezes um numero X se repete dentro do intervalo de 0 até N. Acho que você faz 
(N!)/(N-X)!